# Jersey: ContainerRequestFilter does not get Context ServletRequest

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, ip-address, servlet-filters

To see the full code for this issue, please see this github

https://github.com/mobiusinversion/web-application

I also created this Jersey Jira

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2851

I am working on a `ContainerRequestFilter` using Jersey 2.15.  This is an embedded Jetty app which is shaded into a single jar.

In the Jetty starter (main class):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    Server jettyServer = new Server(10005);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, ServletConstants.COMPONENT_SCAN_ROOT);

    try {
        System.out.println("Starting Jetty");
        jettyServer.start();
        System.out.println("Jetty Started");
        jettyServer.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not start server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}
```

I have a filter which is included via a provider

```
@Provider
public class ExampleProvider implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
        ExampleFilter exampleFilter = new ExampleFilter();
        featureContext.register(exampleFilter);
    }
}
```

Then in the filter:

```
public class ExampleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleFilter.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        logger.info("IP ADDRESS " + servletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
        // ...
    }

}
```

However this produces a `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.filters.ExampleFilter.filter(ExampleFilter.java:29) 
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:131) 
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:67)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

UPDATE: Including pom entried for Jetty and Jersey

```
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.15</jersey.version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.6.v20141205</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that will work since this issue is not reported in those circumstances.  Did you have a look at the github?  Its extremely barebones.  Its clear either Jetty or Jersey or the combination of the two has a bug in this case.  This bounty is to find a solution that does not involve waiting for either group to respond.  Sure, one solution is to ditch Jetty altogether but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mistake was that you **manually created** an instance of `ExampleRequestLoggingFilter` inside the `ExampleRequestFilterProvider`. Dependency injection only works on instances created and managed by the container itself, such as the `ExampleRequestFilterProvider`. This explains why `@Context` injection didn't seem to work in your manually created instance.

A solution would be to move the injection point to the `ExampleRequestFilterProvider` and then pass it through to the constructor of `ExampleRequestLoggingFilter`.

```
@Provider
public class ExampleRequestFilterProvider implements DynamicFeature {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
        ExampleRequestLoggingFilter exampleRequestLoggingFilter = new ExampleRequestLoggingFilter(request);
        featureContext.register(exampleRequestLoggingFilter);
    }

}
```

I tested it here (kudos to the Git project!) and it worked for me.

Note that you're here not passing the actual `HttpServletRequest` instance, but a container managed proxy which delegates further to the actual instance on every method call, so there's nothing to worry as to integrity and threadsafety here.

Comment: Bam, like that...  Thanks man, that really helped.  Clearly I need to hit the books on how this stuff work better.  I can only award bounty in 22 hours but I will.  Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. No hurry with the bounty. You could even leave it open until it expires (and gets auto-awarded). This increases the chance in getting upvotes from people browsing the bounty questions (so you could earn the rep back), particularly during the day before expire.

Comment: Sounds great, will do.  Cheers.

Comment: (+1 good catch) I would just register the filter as a class instead of an instance. It works just the same, but injecting the servlet request into the feature just looks wrong to me :-)

Comment: @peeskillet: it indeed causes some itch because it isn't immediately visible that the `request` instance is actually a proxy. It would be less itchy if the `ExampleRequestLoggingFilter` was created as an anonymous class instead. Or perhaps by renaming the variable name `request` to `requestProxy`. Ah well .. That's up to David :)