# Accessing Request Headers

Tags: java, jax-rs

How to access request headers in implementation of WriterInterceptor interface in JAX-RS?

```
context.getHeaders(); //This line gives a set of response headers(not request headers) in the WriterInterceptor implementation.
```

Complete code below:

```
public class GzipFilterWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GzipFilterWriterInterceptor.class);

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = context.getHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");


    final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
    context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
    context.proceed();
}

}
```

Comment: JAX-RS version? Java / JavaEE version? container version?

Comment: When @Context did not work, was the value null? what was the observed failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement below code to ,see working example at http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/say/Hello

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqCtx, ContainerResponseContext respCtx) throws IOException {

        long startTime=0;
        System.out.println("Adding ProcessingTime in response headers"); 
        if(reqCtx.getHeaderString("startTime")!=null)
        startTime = Long.parseLong(reqCtx.getHeaderString("startTime")); 
        respCtx.getHeaders().add("ProcessingTime",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " millisecs"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqCtx) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Adding start time in request headers");

        reqCtx.getHeaders().add("startTime", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just inject [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html). It will be a thread-local proxy when it's injected, so it's thread safe.

```
@Context
private HttpHeaders headers;
```

It has methods

- [`String getHeaderString(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getHeaderString-java.lang.String-)
- [`List<String> getRequestHeader(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeader-java.lang.String-)
- [`MultivaluedMap<String,String> getRequestHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeaders--)

---

### UPDATE (test)

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Run like any other JUnit test. Only one required dependency:
 * 
 *  <dependency>
 *    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
 *    <scope>test</scope>
 *    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
 *  </dependency>
 */
public class HeadersTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @GET
        public String get() {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class)
                .register(HeaderWriter.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }

    @Provider
    public static class HeaderWriter implements WriterInterceptor {
        @Context
        private HttpHeaders headers;

        @Override
        public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            context.proceed();

            final String header = headers.getHeaderString("X-Request-Header");
            context.getHeaders().add("X-Response-Header", header);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void doit() {
        final Response response = target("hello").request()
                .header("X-Request-Header", "BooYah")
                .get();
        assertThat(response.getHeaderString("X-Response-Header"), is("BooYah"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation (and version) are you using? i tested with Jersey and it worked fine. Maybe other implementations are not the same. I image they should be though in regards to HttpHeaders

Comment: Jersey 2.24 with Jetty embedded as HTTP server.

Comment: My guess would be that you are instantiating the writer when registering it with Jersey. I think this would cause it to be null. If you register it as a class, and let Jersey create it, it should work

Comment: The assertion fails when I run your test. Do you have an idea of the cause ?

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux No, it runs fine for me. How are you running it? I just ran it from an IDE

Comment: with an empty module only with your test it works. Depending on the client which is used the response header can be modified or not. Default client allow that bu other client does not.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Provider
public class GzipFilterWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor
{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GzipFilterWriterInterceptor.class);

    // use a context injection
    @Context 
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = context.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        // do stuff with headers
        if ("Basic Ym9iOnBhc3N3b3Jk".equals(httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("Authorization").get(0)))
        {
            //do stuff here, but be careful about the indexoutofbounds...
        }


        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
        context.proceed();
    }

}
```

The context injection will be injected per request, see the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html%20javadoc).

Comment: please check that neither http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974887/jersey-containerrequestfilter-does-not-get-context-servletrequest, nor https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960 are applicable.

Comment: Does not work! The field headers contains headers pertaining to the WriterInterceptor Context. i.e the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not best solution, but you can have your interceptor implementing ReaderInterceptor. There you can get headers and save them in ThreadLocal variable so you can access then in WriterInterceptor

Also if you have annotation based configuration you can try to inject ContainerRequestContext with a @Context annotation

Comment: I tried to use @Context but it does not work in this context (or I cannot make it work). I would prefer to avoid ThreadLocal variable ;-)

Comment: yes, I got an exception when I try to inject ContainerRequestContext (◊java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
 at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:233))

Comment: And did you annotate interceptor as @RequestScoped?

Comment: Request scope @RequestScoped is the default lifecycle  applied when no annotation is present. See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: Following is valid for resteasy and, I suppose, general for JAX-RS: "If a JAX-RS Provider or javax.ws.rs.Application subclass does not define a scope explicitly, it is bound to the Application scope."

Comment: Also, when u using GET method, the cursor will never go inside the reader Interceptor class implementation bcoz the GET method does not have a body.